# How to define Grails Domain Objects Relationships

Tags: grails, relationship, grails-domain-class

Hi I am new to Grails and I would like to seek your expert advise on how to define the domain class in Grails for the following scenario:

1. A buyer can buy many items
2. A delivery can contain many items, not necessary all the items the buyer has bought, as some items will be delivered at a later time.
3. A delivery cannot contain any new items that the buyer hasn't purchased.

So the following is the relationships between them:

1. One buyer can have many items
2. One buyer can have many deliveries
3. One delivery can have many items

I have defined the domain classes as such; but the result. Can the experts point out to me what I have done wrong? Thank you so much!

```
class Buyer {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String  buyerName
    static hasMany = [purchases : GoodsPurchased]    

}

class GoodsPurchased {

    static constraints = {
        delivery nullable:true
    }

    String goodsName
    static belongsTo = [ buyer: Buyer, delivery : Delivery ]

}

class Delivery {

    static constraints = {
    }

    Date    deliveryDate
    static  belongsTo = [ buyer : Buyer ]
    static  hasMany = [ purchases : GoodsPurchased ]

}
```

A delivery can have one or multiple items that the buyer purchased; as not all the items are necessary for delivery. How do we define in the domain class that - a delivery can only contain items have have been purchased by the buyer before?  How do we do that restriction in Grails?

Comment: without knowing what your problem is its hard to say anything

Comment: though, not sure why you have a `delivery` belonging to a `buyer` here

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this Andy. Sorry i wasn't clear before. When a buyer purchases a few items, the items will get delivered over time. Therefore, each delivery can only contain items that have been bought by the buyer before. I guess my problem is how do I do that restriction in grails - perhaps via a foreign key or something?

Comment: Each delivery is bound to the items purchased by the buyer; so that's why it belongs to the buyer. Does that make sense? Thanks again for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this in the Domain Class, you can check these business rules in the beforeInsert() and the beforeUpdate() that gets fired before the objects are inserted or updated in the domain class.

You can get more information about this here: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/

However, the best place to implement these business logics are still in Services, or restrict the list in GSP for the users to select.

Hope this helps.